# how can i get date value from the GET request, to check which week day it is(if get date is not today)

Tags: python, date, url, weekday

i am new to python. now i am stuck somewhere. here is my problem, how can i get date value from the GET request, to check which week day it is(if get date is not today)
url:

http://10.0.0.5:8000/booking/?format=json&boat_no=1010&date=2000-09-05

i want to find which weekday it is(sunday,monday,tuesday....)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://10.0.0.5:8000/booking/?format=json&boat_no=1010&date=2000-09-05'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['date']
```